# MDX count occurrences per hour over a time

Tags: sql-server, ssas, mdx, ssas-2012

Looking to get an MDX query for SSAS to get the average Report Executions per hour over any time frame.  I"m working with a cube that has SSRS metadata.... and i want to get average Executions per hour.
I figured i have to count how many hours are involved.... as many reports are only run until 5 PM.... so i can't do a straight 24 hour timeframe.

i got something like this so far.... but it's CONSISTENTLY dividing by all hours.... Also i'm already tracking the total counts of executions....

here's the mdx i have... the calc is working, but it keeps dividing everything by 16 for a specific day ... ie.... for 12PM.... it divides by the total transactions by 16 hours.... but the transaction only occurred twice....between 12-1PM.  so it should divide by 2.....

```
   WITH MEMBER [Measures].[Hour Count] AS
        sum(
                [Execution End Time].[24 Hour Time].[Hour 24].MEMBERS,
                IIF([Measures].[Report Execution Count] >= 1,1,0))
        MEMBER [Measures].[Average Exec Per Hour] AS
                ([Measures].[Report Execution Count]/[Measures].[Hour Count])

select
  {[Measures].[Hour Count]
, [Measures].[Report Execution Count] as ['Transaction Count']
, [Measures].[Average Exec Per Hour]}
on Columns
        ,[Execution End Time].[24 Hour Time].[Hour 24]  on Rows
from [BICC DM]
where  ([Execution End Date].[Calendar Dates].[Date Key].&[20160707])
```

[Data extract](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ktB79.jpg)

Comment: an hour occurs once per hour so how would `[Measures].[Hour Count]` ever be more than 1 in that Data Extract you provided?

Comment: the measure keeps a count of how many hours are involved in a particular transaction occurring.  example.  transaction occurs at 12 on monday... and 3pm on tuesday..... 2 hours are involved... so for that report there a 2 will be placed in that measure.

Comment: but you have hours on the rows of your results - so for each hour there is by definition only one hour involved!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the definition of the first measure to below -

```
WITH MEMBER [Measures].[Hour Count] AS
IIF(
    ([Execution End Time].[24 Hour Time].CurrentMember,[Measures].[Report Execution Count])  >= 1,
    1,
    0
   )
```

The issue with your existing measure is the it is evaluating the value for a static set (i.e. `[Execution End Time].[24 Hour Time].[Hour 24].MEMBERS`). I guess what you want to do is evaluate it for the *current* hour instead.

Comment: I thought along these lines originally - but your measure will never return more than 1?

Comment: ummm..i think it will. Here this measure will return the count of transactions that took place in an hour, if I am understanding the questions correctly.

Comment: Anyway, there is definitely an issue with how the measure is built. OP must look into that.

Comment: `IIF(blahblah,1,0)` can only return 1 or 0 ? How could it return anything else? Maybe you need SUM wrapped around it?

Comment: Sir, here the tuple `([Execution End Time].[24 Hour Time].CurrentMember,[Measures].[Report Execution Count])` is validated for every hour. So if that is grt than 1, a 1 is returned, else 0. What am I doing wrong? I am guessing the measure `[Measures].[Report Execution Count]` is defined as some sort "sum" aggregator on the measure group.

Comment: that worked!  thanks!  ah, ok.... so using currentmember we are reiterating and doing the count for each.... it's working now.  have to do some more data validations, but on initial glance it seems to be hitting the right mark.